# How to reference a certain dictionary value based on input variable

Tags: python, dictionary

in python I am asking for a user to input a destination.

The dictionary I have is the following. The value represents the number of miles.

```
LocationsDict = {'Chicago': 220, 'Atlanta': 461}

destination = str(input("What is your destination?"))
```

Say I type in Atlanta, theoretically I should be able to output the value of miles. 
I have tried to do the following to print out the number of miles.

```
print(LocationsDict.values()[destination])
```

When I try this, I get an error. What am I missing? How do a reference a dictionary based on a variable? I know I could always do a massive if statement but that would be too complex.

Comment: `LocationsDict[destination]` is the correct way to extract the values corresponding to a key or use `LocationsDict.get(destination)`

Comment: @BtcSources `dict.values()` doesn't return `list`....`print(type(my_dict.values())` which gives `dict_values` type

Comment: @BtcSources Here's a [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views) to docs.

Comment: @Ch3steR you're completely right, I didn't mean the exact type but to give him an idea, that's why I didn't put it as code. But it is true that it can be misleading, better to remove it.

Comment: @BtcSources Yes, it can be confusing for beginners. That's the reason I posted not being nitpicky. ;)

Comment: @Ch3steR thank you! It was confusing going over the documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dict.values()` returns a list view of values in that dictionary.

You should access the dictionary using the bracket notation `dict[<key>]`:

```
LocationsDict = {'Chicago': 220, 'Atlanta': 461}
destination = 'Atlanta'  # input("What is your destination?")

print(LocationsDict[destination])
```

Output:

```
461
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix your error:

```
LocationsDict = {'Chicago': 220, 'Atlanta': 461}
destination = str(input("What is your destination?"))

print(LocationsDict[destination])
```

But for future error handling you could try:

```
LocationsDict = {'Chicago': 220, 'Atlanta': 461}

destination = str(input("What is your destination?"))
try:
    dist = LocationsDict[destination]
except:
    dist = "There is no data on this location"
print(dist)
```

Comment: Instead of using `try-except` you can use `dict.get(key,'there is no data on this loc')` [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get)

Comment: You can @Ch3steR but I prefer this method (probably because I didn't know you could do it that way!!!) 

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> LocationsDict = {'Chicago': 220, 'Atlanta': 461}
>>> destination = str(input("What is your destination?"))
What is your destination?Atlanta
>>> LocationsDict.values()
dict_values([220, 461])
```

`values` returns an iterable that does not support indexing; you can use it as a `for` loop, but not directly.  That is where you went wrong: you tried to index it as if it were the original dict.

```
>>> type(LocationsDict.values())
<class 'dict_values'>
>>> dist = LocationsDict.values()
>>> dist[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'dict_values' object does not support indexing
```

If you *insist* on using the `values` result, convert it to a list ... but then you have to know the dict order and use an integer index.

```
>>> list(dist)
[220, 461]
>>> dist["Atlanta"]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'dict_values' object is not subscriptable
>>> LocationsDict.values("Atlanta")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: values() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

As others have shown you, one way is to properly call the underlying access routine:

```
>>> LocationsDict.get("Atlanta")
461
```

However, the straightforward way is to use the indexing you should find in your tutorial materials:

```
>>> LocationsDict["Atlanta"]
```